# HSQL: how to get the number of rows updated by an UPDATE statement in a stored procedure

Tags: hsqldb, rowcount

I have a stored procedure, which calls an UPDATE (or INSERT, or DELETE) statement, and I would like to store the number of rows updated by this statement in a locale variable.

This does not work, because INSERT is a statement and cannot be evaluated as an expression:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE f()
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN ATOMIC
  DECLARE rows_updated INT;
  SET rows_updated = (INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(1,2));
  ...
END;
```

Other SQL engines seem to have a "meta-variable" called "@@rowcount" to retrieve the number of rows updated by the last UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE statement of the transaction. I have not found an equivalent in HSQL.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

HSQLDB follows the SQL:2008 Standard. You can set your rows_updated variable with the GET DIAGNOSTICS statement. There is also a function that mimics this statement.

See here:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_diagnostics_state